# Constructing a Pushdown Automaton

Tags: pushdown-automaton

In my lectrures we are given an example of a pushdown automaton that accepts the following language {(a^n)(b^n): n is greater than or equal to zero}.

```
Q - set of states ={s,p,f}
L - alphabet = {a,b}
R - stack = {a}
F - accepting states ={s,f}
D -transition relation ={
(s,a,e),(p,a)
(p,a,e),(p,a)
(p,b,a),(f,e)}
```

My question is why the states p and f are necessary? Could you not just use the state s?

Also I was wondering when constructing a PDA is there a method to know how many states you will need and what the stack alphabet will be? Or do you just have to solve it intuitively?

Answer (score 0):

In case of not having the state p, the PDA would accept any string having the same number of a's and b's.

There is no non-intuitive method to know the number of states or transitions beforehand, as we are going to convert a non formal description to a formal one, so there is no formal way!